# Force Stack to use an existing Stack/GHC installation instead of re-creating one from scratch

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

When pulling the most recent Docker Stack LTS image from Dockerhub, a full Stack installation with GHC can be found in `/home/stackage/.stack`.

However, when doing `stack path --stack-root`, Stack will forcefully rebuild an entire Stack/GHC installation into a `global-project` subdirectory. Even if we previously set the `STACK_ROOT` env variable to `/home/stackage/.stack`.

```sh
$ docker run --rm -it fpco/stack-build:lts-17.13 sh
$ export STACK_ROOT=/home/stackage/.stack
$ echo $(stack path --stack-root)

Writing implicit global project config file to: /home/stackage/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml
Note: You can change the snapshot via the resolver field there.
Using latest snapshot resolver: lts-17.13
Preparing to install GHC to an isolated location.
This will not interfere with any system-level installation.
Preparing to download ghc-8.10.4 ...
ghc-8.10.4: download has begun
...
```

How can we force Stack to recognise the existing installation in `/home/stackage/.stack` and not have it create another one in `/home/stackage/.stack/global-project` ? Nothing in the Stack documentation seems to mention this aspect.

Comment: um... is weird, the env variable `GHC_VERSION=8.8.4` doesn't match the version used by the lts, since lts-17.13 uses version `ghc-8.10.4`. I don't know about the docker image, but It seems wrong to me... Can you check ghc version?

Comment: Just to understand, why are you mentioning `GHC_VERSION=8.8.4` here? I can only see `8.10.4` being mentioned on the above output.

Comment: I mean the docs for the [image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/fpco/stack-build/lts-17.13/images/sha256-1c70bdef874125a003f0ce0e4a48e65103e4a8fee49f74c485d8ea05088a2bf5?context=explore) has an input variable which's default is `8.8.4`

Comment: @lsmor ah!! This might explain that